# Find all solutions to $f\left(x^2+xf(y)\right)=xf(x+y)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, functional-equations

> Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $$f\left(x^2+xf(y)\right)=xf(x+y)$$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

This is somewhat related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1133472/find-all-real-functions-f-mathbb-r-to-mathbb-r-satisfying-the-equation?noredirect=1&lq=1), but with an $xf(y)$ term instead of $yf(x)$. I've managed to get $f(0)=0$, $f\left(x^2\right)=xf(x)$ and $f$ is odd, but not much more. I think that $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=0$ are the only solutions, but I'm not sure.

Comment: pay attention that if theres $k\ne0$ such that $f(k)=0$ then: $$xf(x) = f(x^2) = f(x^2+xf(k))=xf(x+k)$$ that means that for every $x\in\Bbb{R}$, $f(x)=f(x+k)$

Comment: Now suppose there is no $k\neq 0$ s.t. $f(k)=0$. Setting $y=-x$ you get that $f(x^2+xf(-x))=0$ and therefore $x^2+xf(-x)=0$ and therefore $f(-x)=-x$ for all $x$.

Comment: How can did you manage to prove that $ f $ is odd?

Comment: $xf(x)=f(x^2)=-xf(-x)\implies f(x)=-f(-x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function defined by $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is a solution to the functional equation.

Suppose that $f$ is some other solution. Then there is a real number $c$ such that $f(c) \neq 0$.

For any $r \in \mathbb{R}$, let $x = \frac{r}{f(c)}$, and let $y = c - x$. The functional equation then gives us that
$$
  f \left( x^2 + xf(y) \right) = xf(x + y) = xf(c) = \frac{r}{f(c)} \cdot f(c) = r
$$
showing that $r \in f(\mathbb{R})$. i.e. The function is surjective.

As you noted, we have that $f(0) = 0$, which follows by taking $x = y = 0$ in the functional equation.

Now let $x = -f(y)$ in the functional equation. We obtain that
$$
  0 = f(0) = f \left( f(y)^2 - f(y) f(y) \right) = -f(y) f(y - f(y))
$$
for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$, we have that if $f(y) = 0$, then $f(y - f(y)) = f(y) = 0$, and if $f(y) \neq 0$, then $-f(y) f(y - f(y)) = 0$ implies that $f(y - f(y)) = 0$. We thus have that
$$
  f(y - f(y)) = 0
$$
for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$.

Also as noted by you, we have that $f(x^2) = xf(x)$ by taking $y = 0$ in the functional equation.

Now for any real number $x$, we showed earlier that there is some $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(y) = x$.

We then have that
$$
  xf(x) = f(y) f(f(y)) = f(f(y)^2) = f \left( f(y)^2 + f(y) f \left( y - f(y) \right) \right)
$$
using the fact that $f(y - f(y)) = 0$. The functional equation then gives us that
$$
  xf(x) = f(y) f \left( f(y) + y - f(y) \right) = f(y) f(y) = x^2
$$
holds for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. For $x = 0$, we already have that $f(x) = 0 = x$. If $x \neq 0$, then we can divide the previous relation by $x$ to find again that $f(x) = x$. We thus conclude that $f(x) = x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score -1):

Since you've allready know that, I'll continue from $f(0) = 0$ and $xf(x)=f(x^2)$

first, see that for every $x\ne0$: $$-xf(-x)=f\left(\left(-x\right)^2\right)=f(x^2)=xf(x)$$
$$f(x)=-f(-x)$$
Now, for every $a>0$:
$$f(a)=\sqrt{a}f(\sqrt{a})$$
which means:
$$f(a)=a^{\frac{1}{2}}f(a^{\frac{1}{2}})=a^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot a^{\frac{1}{4}}f(a^{\frac{1}{4}})=a^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot a^{\frac{1}{4}}\cdot a^{\frac{1}{8}}f(a^{\frac{1}{8}})=\dots=a^{\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}}f(a^{\frac{1}{2^n}})$$
therefore:
$$f(a)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a^{\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}}f(a^{\frac{1}{2^n}})}
=
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a^{\frac{2^n-1}{2^n}}}\cdot\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{f(a^{\frac{1}{2^n}})}=af\left(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{a^{\frac{1}{2^n}}}\right)=af(1)$$
which means basicly that theres $m\in\Bbb{R}$ such that for every $a>0$, $f(a)=ma$. But now, for every $a<0$: $$f(a)=-f(-a)=-m\cdot(-a)=ma$$
therefore $f(a)=ma$ for every $x\in\Bbb{R}$

Comment: I would love to get an explanation where I was wrong from someone who gave me -1.

Comment: How do you know $f$ is continuous?

Comment: I thought it's part of the assumptions...

Comment: @EugenCovaci A lot of functional equations can be proven to be continuous and even then he showed what all continuous functions following that functional equation must be. Surprised by the down votes.

Comment: @WillFisher Yes, it can be proven, but one cannot use this as a fact until it is indeed proven.

Comment: @EugenCovaci You can assume it to be true albeit your answer only gives the required form of continuous functions.

Comment: Firstly, could we prove that $f$ needs to be continuous? Secondly, plugging in $f(x)=mx$ implies $m=0,1$, no?