# Can this fuctional equation be solved?

Tags: functional-equations

$f: \mathbb{R}^{+}  \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+}$

$f(x^2)=xf(x)$

$f(x+1)=f(x)+1$

Can this functional equation be solved ?

Comment: Yes, it can be solved by you.

Comment: Or at the very least, attempted by you.

Comment: For $f$ continuous this has been solved on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/109458/fx2-xfx-implies-that-fx-mx).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps obvious but what about
$$f(x)=x?$$

Comment: What about it? Do you think this is an answer?

Comment: Yes. It works but just seemed too obvious.

Comment: The point is to find, with proof, all solutions. No?

Comment: More often than not, solving functional equations involves finding _all_ solutions, not just one. So yes, it's probably too obvious.